# SELECT inside trigger gives wrong result (it ignores the WHERE clause)

Tags: innodb, mariadb, trigger

When I run this code inside an after UPDATE trigger:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `stock_totals` WHERE `product_id` = 2 AND `stock_place_id` = 3 INTO OUTFILE 'query3.csv'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get this into `query3.csv`: (field order: product_id, stock_place_id, date, quantity)

```
"1","3","2020-01-01","42"
```

Notice how the resulting row does not match the WHERE clause: the stock_place_id is correct, **but the product_id is wrong** (I got 1, but it should be 2).

When the same query is ran alone, I get an empty table which is the expected result given my data:

```
+------------+----------------+------------+----------+
| product_id | stock_place_id | date       | quantity |
+------------+----------------+------------+----------+
|          1 |              1 | 2020-01-01 |      -42 |
|          1 |              3 | 2020-01-01 |       42 |
+------------+----------------+------------+----------+
```

---

I'm running MariaDB version 10.4.12 and innodb_version 10.4.12 on Arch Linux.

The full query for the `stock_totals` table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `stock_totals` (
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `stock_place_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`stock_place_id`,`date`),
 KEY `fk_stock_totals_stock_place1_idx` (`stock_place_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_stock_totals_product1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_stock_totals_stock_place1` FOREIGN KEY (`stock_place_id`) REFERENCES `stock_place` (`place_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this with MariaDB 10.4.12 with `innodb_version` 10.4.12 on Fedora Linux, but I don't see the problem you have - I get an empty `query3.csv` file. The only difference I have (besides the Linux distro) is that I don't have your foreign key constraints since I don't have those tables.

Are you sure you're looking at the correct output file?

Note also that you will get a warning when you run the query or create a trigger with that query:

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                               |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1287 | '<select expression> INTO <destination>;' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use 'SELECT <select list> INTO <destination> FROM...' instead |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

So you could try moving the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses to the end of the statement. I get the same result with this, just without the warning.

You can also try enumerating the columns in the `SELECT` instead of `SELECT *`, just to see if it changes anything.

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER UPDATE ON stock_totals 
  FOR EACH ROW 
    SELECT * FROM `stock_totals` 
    WHERE `product_id` = 2 AND `stock_place_id` = 3 
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/query10.csv'  
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'         
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```